# Do Cloud Vendors ensure ACID properties while offering Relational Database services?

Tags: database, cloud-computing

ACID properties are important for the RDMS applications.There are many relational database services offered by the cloud providers such as AMAZON RDS and Microsoft SQL Azure.

i'm curious about if the ACID properties are provided or not ?

thanks.

Comment: Why not ask the provider?

Comment: why serverfauls exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually i read  a good paper which talks about my question, i wanted to post here for further users.
From DAVID CHAPPELL OCTOBER 2008, INTRODUCING THE AZURE SERVICES PLATFORM AN EARLY LOOK AT WINDOWS AZURE, .NET SERVICES, SQL SERVICES, AND LIVE SERVICES

> SQL Data Services, formerly known as
>   SQL Server Data Services, provides a
>   database in the cloud. As the figure
>   suggests, this technology lets
>   on-premises and cloud applications
>   store and access data on Microsoft
>   servers in Microsoft data centers. As
>   with other cloud technologies, an
>   organization pays only for what it
>   uses, increasing and decreasing usage
>   (and cost) as the organization’s needs
>   change. Using a cloud database also
>   allows converting what would be
>   capital expenses, such as investments
>   in disks and database management
>   systems (DBMSs), into operating
>   expenses. A primary goal of SQL Data
>   Services is to be broadly accessible.
>   Toward this end, it exposes both SOAP
>   and RESTful interfaces, allowing its
>   data to be accessed in various ways.
>   And because this data is exposed
>   through standard protocols, SQL Data
>   Services can be used by applications
>   on any kind of system—it’s not a
>   Windows-only technology. Unlike the
>   Windows Azure storage service, SQL
>   Data Services is built on Microsoft
>   SQL Server. Nonetheless, the service
>   does not expose a traditional
>   relational interface. Instead, SQL
>   Data Services provides a hierarchical
>   data model that doesn’t require a
>   pre-defined schema. Each data item
>   stored in this service is kept as a
>   property with its own name, type, and
>   value. To query this data,
>   applications can use direct RESTful
>   access or a language based on the C#
>   syntax defined by Microsoft’s Language
>   Integrated Query (LINQ).
>
> There’s an obvious question here: **Why
>   not just offer SQL Server in the
>   cloud? Why instead provide a cloud
>   database service that uses an approach
>   different from what most of us already
>   know?** One answer is that providing
>   this slightly different set of
>   services offers some advantages. SQL
>   Data Services can provide better
>   scalability, availability, and
>   reliability than is possible by just
>   running a relational DBMS in the
>   cloud.
>
> The way it organizes and retrieves
>   data makes replication and load
>   balancing easier and faster than with
>   a traditional relational approach.
>   Another advantage is that SQL Data
>   Services doesn’t require customers to
>   manage their own DBMS. Rather than
>   worry about the mechanics, such as
>   monitoring disk usage, servicing log
>   files, and determining how many
>   instances are required, a SQL Data
>   Services customer can focus on what’s
>   important: the data. And finally,
>   Microsoft has announced plans to add
>   more relational features to SQL Data
>   Services. Expect its functionality to
>   grow.

Answer (score 1):

AWS RDS looks to be based off of mysql 5.1, and SQL Azure is based off of SQL Server.  Both of those platforms are ACID compliant, seems a fair bet that RDS/SQL Azure are as well.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i said they provide ACID but not scalability, that's the point i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

These offerings are scalable not by virtue of architecture (like most key/value stores); but simply because they can offer big honking servers if you pay for them, and I guess they both have a well-tuned installation and experienced staff for keeping them running.

As Tony [said](https://serverfault.com/questions/137791/do-cloud-vendors-ensure-acid-properties-while-offering-relational-database-servic/137811#137811), they're based on traditional SQL servers (MySQL andMSSQLServer, respectively), make no mistake, this is real software and can really deliver when properly tuned on appropriate hardware.

Comment: good point so they never benefit the key/value based distributed storage for relational database services, it means they provide ACID properties and but not scalability.i think it's not a good idea to movie my databases to cloud.

Comment: obviously, that's your choice to make; but i think you should try before dismissing them.  The current "SQL doesn't scale" phrase is more fad than true.  key/value stores are trivial to scale horizontally; but that doesn't mean everything else is suddenly inadequate.  There has been lots of huge databases for decades already.  most of them are on SQL systems.